# Make a new sublist of preceding characters every time there's a zero in a list, excluding the zero

Tags: python, list, grouping, sublist

The list I have to manipulate is longer, but for example let's use a list that is              `[3,5,0,6,8,9,7,0,1,0]`. The amount of elements between zero is not constant. I want to group the terms preceding a zero into sublists. What I'm looking for is `[[3,5],[6,8,9,7],[1]]`; the zeros split the terms but aren't included in the sublist.

I don't think I can use the `split` function because I'm grouping elements, so I'm stuck trying to figure out a method of grouping this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> L = [3,5,0,6,8,9,7,0,1,0]
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(L, key=bool) if k]
[[3, 5], [6, 8, 9, 7], [1]]
```

`key=bool` works in this case, since `0` is considered *empty* but as @AshwiniChaudhary noted you will have to use a custom `key` function in the case when you are not splitting by `0` eg. splitting by `2`

```
key=lambda x: x != 2
```

---

**Explanation:**

Firstly I'll illustrate how the `key` works:

```
>>> bool(3), bool(5)
(True, True)
>>> bool(0)
False
```

As you can see, it will either return `True` or `False`, `False` on `0` and `True` on anything else. (Actually `bool('')` and `bool([])` also return `False`, as well as any other empty builtin object but we are only considering numbers here)

So `groupby` is simply grouping the result of the `key` function, therefore groups of `0`s and `1`s.

```
>>> [(key, group) for key, group in groupby(L, key=bool)]
[(True, <itertools._grouper object at 0xb6fc1dac>), (False, <itertools._grouper object at 0xb6fc432c>), (True, <itertools._grouper object at 0xb6fc422c>), (False, <itertools._grouper object at 0xb6fc4c2c>), (True, <itertools._grouper object at 0xb6fc428c>), (False, <itertools._grouper object at 0xb6fc476c>)]
```

But as you can see the group, is a weird object, an `itertools._grouper` object. Why doesn't it just return a list? `itertools` is grouping the items *lazily* which is much more efficient, but that leaves the job to us to consume all the items in the group into a `list`.

```
>>> [(key, list(group)) for key, group in groupby(L, key=bool)]
[(True, [3, 5]), (False, [0]), (True, [6, 8, 9, 7]), (False, [0]), (True, [1]), (False, [0])]
```

However we don't need the `key`, we just need to check if it's `True` and return only the items that satisfy this predicate, which leads to my answer at the beginning.

```
>>> [list(group) for key, group in groupby(L, key=bool) if key]
[[3, 5], [6, 8, 9, 7], [1]]
```

Comment: +1 Better use `key = lambda x : x != 0`, as it'll allow you to split at any element.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with lambda or the structure of that for loop I'm more used to `for i in x:`, and not the list before the for as well as the if statement after the for. Could you explain a little bit what's going on there (in the for loop and what you're doing with lambda). Also, is 2 just an arbitrary number. I hope it's not too much to explain but if you could at least guide me towards some documentation it'd be very helpful.

Comment: @BennetLeff Yes `2` is an abritray example. First you will have to read what a [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is and then read up on [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) Please tell me if you have any further queries after reading those

Comment: After some reading this makes a lot more sense. I'm still a little confused, does this entire line `[list(g) for k, g in groupby(L, key=bool) if k]` return the new list with sublists or is that a variable value. If it's a variable, which one. I tried printing each variable but none of them seem to be assigned to the new list.

Comment: To clarify it works on the command line, but I need to manipulate the new list so how can I get the new list. For instance if I wanted to assign the output of this function to the variable splitList, how would I do this.

Comment: @BennetLeff `splitList = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(L, key=bool) if k]`

Answer (score 1):

a relatively ridiculous one-line version:

```
>>> L = [3,5,0,6,8,9,7,0,1,0]
>>> [ map(int, str(r)) for r in "".join([str(r) for r in L]).rstrip("0").split("0") ]
[[3, 5], [6, 8, 9, 7], [1]]
```

no import of new modules though.

Comment: *relatively* should be crossed out

Comment: what if `L` had elements like 701, 10 etc,